# Throwing paper/ball effect animation in Swift UIKit

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

What would be the best way to create a throwing paper/ball effect animation in UIKit?

What I need is basically a throwing effect starting from `point A` and ending at `Point B`. I don't need any bouncing effects, this is more of an effect to let the user know that something was added from `point A` to `Point B`; similar to the effect we get when we add a photo to an album in Photos.

I have been playing around with `animateKeyframes` but I cannot quite get the effect I want, I'm not getting the curve path and I cannot change the speed so the effect doesn't look realistic.

```
@IBAction func startAnimation(_ sender: Any) {
    UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations: {
        var startTime = 0.0
        var viewScale:CGFloat = 1.0
        
        for i in 0..<5{
            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: startTime, relativeDuration: 0.25, animations: {
                self.myView.center =  CGPoint(x: self.myView.center.x + 10, y: self.myView.center.y - 20)
                self.myView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: viewScale, y: viewScale)
            })
            startTime += 0.1
            viewScale += 0.01
        }
        
        for i in 0..<5{
            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: startTime, relativeDuration: 0.25, animations: {
                self.myView.center =  CGPoint(x: self.myView.center.x + 10, y: self.myView.center.y + 5)
                self.myView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: viewScale, y: viewScale)
            })
            startTime += 0.1
            viewScale -= 0.01
        }
    }
    )
}
```

[image]

Comment: "What would be the best way" is very broad and vague. Can you be more specific? What's the issue with the code you've shown? (My guess is: it's that the animation doesn't follow a curved path. But it would be better to be clear about it.)

Comment: Yes, I'm not getting the curve path so the effect doesn't look realistic. Also, with `animateKeyframes` I cannot find a way to change the speed to make it more realistic. In other words, I'm not sure if  `animateKeyframes` is the best tool for this type of animation. I have updated my original question.

Comment: Well, I can think of three approaches: (1) keyframe with three points and a cubic interpolation; (2) springing animation; (3) UIKit dynamics.

Comment: Ok, I'll look into all options especially the three-point with the cubic interpolation. I for some reason though I would need Core Animation.

Comment: Gave it as an answer, see below.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out the three-point with the cubic interpolation option. I'm getting there.

Comment: Please don't include an answer as part of the Question. You can answer your own question as an Answer.

Comment: Well, your answer led me to the right answer so I think it's fair to leave yours as the right answer. Thanks.

Comment: You can keep mine as accepted if you like, but your final code should still be in an answer, not inserted into the question.

Comment: Done, I moved the code to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this result is totally terrible:

[image]

That's a keyframe animation with three points (start, apex, end) and a cubic interpolation as its calculation mode. Playing around with the numbers might improve it a little.

If you don't like that, you might prefer to use UIKit dynamics to get something more physics-based. (But I also tried it with UIKit dynamics and it wasn't better.)

Comment: That is exactly the effect I want and I almost have it I just don't see the animation from start to apex, I think it happening too fast that is not visible. I think it has to do with the numbers I'm using in the `withRelativeStartTime:` and the  `relativeDuration:`. I'm using 0.0, 0.5 and .05 for `thewithRelativeStartTime` and 0.25 for all `relativeDuration` would you mind sharing your numbers?

Comment: I think I got it close to how I want it. I have updated the original question with my final code.

Comment: I don't think it makes much sense to divide your duration and start times by 5 when there are only three points.

Comment: Agreed.  @ matt -  Question:  What program did you use to create the gif file you posted showing the animation?

Comment: I use ScreenFlow, but there are other ways. :)

Comment: Oh ok, so you basically created a video and then converted to a gif, got it. I think I could use Quicktime since I don't have ScreenFlow.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete code after implementing the three-point with the cubic interpolation animation that `matt` suggested.

```
 @IBAction func startAnimation(_ sender: Any) {
    myView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: pointA.center.x - 25, y: pointA.center.y - 25, width: 50, height: 50))
    myView?.backgroundColor = .blue
    myView?.layer.cornerRadius = myView!.frame.height / 2
    view.addSubview(myView!)
    
    UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 1.5, delay: 0.0, options: [.calculationModeCubic], animations: {
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0, relativeDuration: 0.2, animations: {
            self.myView!.center =  CGPoint(x: self.pointA.center.x, y: self.pointA.center.y)
        })
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.0, relativeDuration: 0.9, animations: {
            self.myView!.center =  CGPoint(x: self.pointB.center.x + 75, y: self.pointB.center.y - 50 )
            self.myView!.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.75, y: 0.75)
        })
        
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.1, relativeDuration: 0.7, animations: {
            self.myView!.center =  CGPoint(x: self.pointB.center.x, y: self.pointB.center.y)
            self.myView!.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.2, y: 0.2)
        })
    }, completion: { _ in
        self.myView?.removeFromSuperview()
    })
}
```