# What is the proper way to scale a view while animating it with CAKeyframeAnimation and BezierPath

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

The following code effectively animates and scales a view along a `BezierPath` but I feel like I'm cheating since I'm mixing `UIKit` and `CAKeyframeAnimation` (Core Animation) animations.

Is there a better way to scale a view while animating it along the `BezierPath`?

```
func animateIt(){

    let myView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
    myView.backgroundColor = .blue
    myView.layer.cornerRadius = myView.frame.height / 2
    view.addSubview(myView)
        
    let startPoint = CGPoint(x: 250, y: 500)
    let apexPoint = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 50)
    let endPoint = CGPoint(x: 50, y: 350)
    let durationTime = 1.5
    
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.move(to: startPoint)
    path.addQuadCurve(to: endPoint, controlPoint: apexPoint)

    let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")
    animation.path = path.cgPath
    animation.duration = durationTime
    myView.layer.add(animation, forKey: "bezier")
    myView.center = endPoint
    
    UIView.animate(withDuration: durationTime, animations: {
        myView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.5, y: 0.5);
    })
}
```

I tried using a second `CAKeyframeAnimation` animation instead of the `UIKit` animation and used the array of key values but no matter what I do, I cannot get a uniform scale, it scales at the beginning but not at the end.

```
   let scaleAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "scale")
   scaleAnimation.values = [1.0, 0.9, 0.5,]
   myView.layer.add(scaleAnimation, forKey: "scale")
```

Thanks!

Comment: But if you go back to my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/64973169/341994 and watch the screencast carefully you will see that I _do_ both animate the position and animate the scale (smoothly from start to finish). The use of the bezier path for the position doesn't change anything about that.

Comment: Hmm, did you use the values array to do the scale?

Comment: I just attached a second animation to the layer. It could have been a keyframe animation but your original spec didn't seem to ask for that; it looked to me like a smooth scaling over time. So it was just a plain basic animation.

Comment: So, you don't see any issue by using mixing `UIKit` and `CAKeyframeAnimation` animations? To me, it would make more sense to add a second `CAKeyframeAnimation` for the scaling but as I said I'm having issues getting a smooth scaling.

Comment: I didn't mix them. I used CAKeyframeAnimation for the position and CABasicAnimation for the scale. I do not know what your "issues" are because you didn't show that code.

Comment: And if you decide you really want a CAKeyframeAnimation for the scale, why then we are right back at the previous answer: you need to use a cubic interpolation.

Comment: Look at the code I posted in my original question above, I'm showing the `CAKeyframeAnimation` and at the bottom, I'm using a `UIKit` animation for the scaling. I'm getting the effect I want but I feel like missing UIKit and CAKeyFrameAnimation is not right.

Comment: If you're getting the effect you want, then stop. There is nothing actually being "mixed". Under the hood, all animation is layer animation. View animation is just a notation. Basically you are doing exactly what I did in my screencast; the scaling is _not_ a keyframe animation, it is a single basic animation.

Comment: That was basically my question. Thanks a lot! - FYI - This is my first time using CAKeyframeAnimation and BezierPaths and to be quite honest I found it a little confusing.